# Why do I get "Can't call method "fetchrow_array" without a package or object reference"?

Tags: perl, dbd

I have installed [DBD::Pg](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Pg/Pg.pm) version 2.17.1 but still still getting error while using below code

```
$res = $conn->prepare($query);
$res = $res->execute();
@tuple = $res->fetchrow_array;
```

error:

```
Can't call method "fetchrow_array" without a package or object reference at test.pl line 69.
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Give us more code. What it `$res`?

Comment: I have added the values or $res. please let me know if you require more script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$res` is not an object instance of `DBI`. Try running `ref $res`: it should return an empty string.

> Executes a previously prepared
>   statement. In addition to UPDATE,
>   DELETE, INSERT statements, for which
>   it returns always the number of
>   affected rows, the execute method can
>   also be used for SELECT ... INTO table
>   statements.

Your `$res` most likely contains the number of "affected rows".

```
$sth   = $conn->prepare($query);
$nrows = $sth->execute();
@tuple = $sth->fetchrow_array;
```

Comment: i tried as per your suggestion but no success. still getting the same error.

Comment: I had a typo: `@tuple = $res->fetchrow_array;` should be `@tuple = $sth->fetchrow_array;`

Answer (score 6):

You should not be saying

```
$res = $res->execute();
```

$res before that statement is the statement handle that you will need to use to call fetchrow_array after the execute succeeds, but the above is replacing it with the return value of execute(), which is the number of rows affected if successful or undef if the execute failed.  Instead, store that return value in a separate variable if desired and check it for success before calling fetchrow_array.

Comment: @Space, then you're doing it wrong, because this is your problem.  Post your revised code.